# Maintaining array order in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, loops

I am new to JavaScript and I am having trouble working with my array, I want my array ordered how I explicitly write it and not how JavaScript decides it wants it.

If we have a array

```
var array = {
    0: 'zero',
    4: 'four',
    2: 'two'
};
```

When I choose to display this in the console, or iterate over it, Its reordered like this

```
array = {
    0: 'zero',
    2: 'two',
    4: 'four'
};
```

I have tried 2 loops so far, The for loop, and also the for loop with the in statement.
Both work according how I assumed they would as they use a key and work there way up/down, making order I specify is absolutely useless.

How can I write/print/work with my array as its ordered, In other languages such as PHP its as simple as

```
$array = array(
    0 => 'zero',
    4 => 'four',
    2 => 'two'
);

foreach($array as $key => $value)
    echo $key ."\n";
```

This would output

```
0
4
2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It actually seems to be an object.

Comment: How can I work with the Array and maintain order?

Comment: As voiced here, an object is not an array. Find out what an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) are in Javascript.

Comment: @cecilli0n Check answers below. They have the solution.

Comment: Folks, the question is : how to print `0` then `4` then `2` doing `for (var k in array) console.log(k)`?

Comment: I have read and responded to all solutions below, They don't have the answer below like you say, I spoke about iterating over the array to write/print/handle it in the order it is explicitly written in, Nobody has addressed this yet, Everybody has just jumped on the band wagon in shouting "Is not a array its a object", My question still goes unanswered.

Comment: Show us how you are iterating in Javascript. [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) or perhaps [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: @Xotic750 `for in` fails for me with Chrome. See previous comment.

Comment: @wared Read [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) > Iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can be executed.

Comment: @Xotic750 Which means? The fact is that Chrome prints `0` then `2` then `4`, so, is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: It means what it states, what are you unclear about? It doesn't matter if it is Chrome, FireFox or Sky Blue Pink. The way to avoid it is to use an `Array` and not an `Object`, and use array iteration rather than object iteration. Go and read the links that I posted above to get an understanding of what each is, there are examples there.

Comment: @Xotic750 I mean, the interesting part is "in arbitrary order" right? Is there a way to avoid this, yes|no? That's it :)

Comment: Yes, there are techniques that you can use to avoid it being arbitrary. But that deserves a whole question of its own.

Comment: @Xotic750 Well, it seems to me that it's precisely the question. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the question to me but, a misunderstanding of Javascript. If that is the question then it should be updated to clarify this otherwise it deserves a close vote.

Comment: @Xotic750 "a misunderstanding of Javascript", I didn't see it that way, I understand now.

Comment: Actually wared is correct, The question itself is represented correctly by the title, "maintaining array order in javascript", The fact that I used incorrect syntax which lead to a object being created and not an array did need to be pointed out, but that doesn't necessarily mean it answers the question. Talking about maintaining order does not need another question of its own, That is this original question. It  does not need or deserve a close vote.

Comment: @Xotic750 So what does seem to be the question to you?

Comment: An array is always ordered, and object is not. Please update your question to clarify with your new understanding of Javascript terminology. See my answer, I posted it for you.

Comment: It seems even more clear to me now that my conclusion was correct rather than @wared after you duplicated your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615911/force-order-of-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 7):

You're using an object `{}`, not an array `[]`. Objects have no explicit order, where Arrays do. That's why you're having your problem. Change your `{}` to `[]` and you'll be fine. You could even use an array of objects.

```
var array = [
    {0: 'zero'}, 
    {4: 'four'}, 
    {2: 'two'}
];
```

Looping over that like so

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  console.log(array[i]);
}
```

Gives us our normal order.

```
Object {0: "zero"}
Object {4: "four"}
Object {2: "two"}
```

Another Edit: The problem is you're trying to have an array that has properties and values just like an object, without using an object, {property: value} - that can't really be done with an array. To loop over an array like you want, it's as simple as

```
var arr = [1,2,3]
```

and

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  console.log(i) //1,2,3
}
```

but the problem, like mentioned above, is you want more complex arrays which you simply can't do.

Comment: Well he can't *just* change the initial declaration; the initialization syntax is different as well.

Comment: Pointy this is what I just tried and indeed it failed, A pretty useless statement. However along with this, When I did get the correct syntax to create a array, My question still goes unanswered as to how to iterate over it and main the key order, I just tried again with the loops I mentioned and the same problem I had with the object exists within the array.

Comment: @cecilli0n try it now. Sorry was editing the answer.

Comment: You could also use nested arrays like `[[0, 'zero'], [4, 'four'], [2, 'two']]`.

Comment: This answer seriously confuses what is essentially a simple question where the OP doesn't know the difference between an `Array` and an `Object` or how to iterate over either of them.

Comment: Or even a single array like `[0, 'zero', 4, 'four', 2, 'two']`, doing `i += 2`.

Comment: Guys, When I use this for loop, How can I display to the screen the output? I am trying alert(array[i]) and alert([i]) within the for loop, but it returns "[object Object]", So I feel I am unable to choose the correct answer as I cannot test some of these answers to verify. When I was previously using a object which I thought was a array, the same alert(array[i]) produced the value stored in array[i].

Comment: I think you're fundamentally not understanding the difference between an array and an object. You can't alert an object, so instead of alert do console.log(array[i]) and you'll see the output in the console.

Comment: I am just using alert as a way to verify which position we are at within the loop, What way other than the console can you recommend to do this?

Comment: Look up what a break statement is and use that. Or look up what 'debugger' in chrome is and use that.

Comment: @cecilli0n http://wawawared.github.io/miniconsole/?%22var%20array%20%3D%20%5B%5B0%2C%2C%20%27zero%27%5D%2C%2C%20%5B4%2C%2C%20%27four%27%5D%2C%2C%20%5B2%2C%2C%20%27two%27%5D%5D%3B%22%2C%22var%20i%20%3D%20-1%3B%20while%20(%2B%2Bi%20%3C%20array.length)%20log(array%5Bi%5D%5B0%5D%2C%2C%20array%5Bi%5D%5B1%5D)%3B%22.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand what an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and what an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) are, they are fundamentally different things and do not behave the same.

> Array
>
> Arrays are list-like objects whose prototype has methods to perform traversal and mutation operations. Neither the length of a JavaScript array nor the types of its elements are fixed. Since an array's size length grow or shrink at any time, JavaScript arrays are not guaranteed to be dense. In general, these are convenient characteristics; but if these features are not desirable for your particular use, you might consider using typed arrays.

Examples of an Array, note the magical `length` property, the values assigned to an Array are always found at their indexed locations; index is from 0 to 2^32 - 1

```
// dense arrays
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];

array1.length === 3;
array1[0] === 1;

var array2 = [];

array2[0] = 1;
array2[1] = 2;
array2[2] = 3;

array2.length === 3;
array1[1] === 2;

var array3 = [];

array3.push(1);
array3.push(2);
array3.push(3);

array3.length === 3;
array3[2] === 3;

// and a sparse array
var array4 = [];

array4[0] = 1;
array4[2] = 2;
array4[4] = 3;

array4.length === 5;
array4[1] === undefined;
```

Iterating an array [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (var index = 0; index < array.length; index += 1) { // counts from (index) 0 to 4
    console.log(index, array[index]); // outputs 0 1 \n 1 2 \n 2 3 \n 3 4 \n 4 5
}
```

> Object
>
> An object is a collection of properties, and a property is an association between a name and a value. A property's value can be a function, in which case the property is known as a method. In addition to objects that are predefined in the browser, you can define your own objects.

Examples of an Object, there is no magical `length` property.

```
var object1 = {
    'zero': 1,
    'one': 2,
    'two': 3
};

object1.zero === 1;

var object2 = {);

object2['zero'] = 1;
object2['one'] = 2;
object2['two'] = 3;

object2.one === 2;

var object3 = {);

object3.zero = 1;
object3.one = 2;
object3.two = 3;

object['two'] === 3;
```

Iterating (enumerating)  an object [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
var object = {
   one: 0,
   two: 1,
   three: 2
};

for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) { // make sure the property belongs to object
        console.log(property, object[property]); // outputs (not necessarily this order)
                                                 // three 2 \n two 1 \n one 0
    }
};
```

If you are trying to maintain an ordered Object, then this is not how Javascript works and iteration (enumeration) of an object is arbitrary. There are techniques that you can use to iterate (enumerate) an Object in a known order. This requires that you keep an ordered list of properties in an array and use the array in the iteration process.

```
var object = {
   'c': 1,
   'z': 2,
   'b': 3,
   'a': 4
}

var propertyOrder = ['c', 'z', 'b', 'a'];

for (var index = 0; index < propertyOrder.length; index += 1) {
    console.log(index, propertyOrder[index], object[propertyOrder[index]]); // outputs 0 c 1 \n 1 z 2 \n 2 b 3 \n 3 a 4
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't get it. What makes you think that 0, then 4, then 2, is in any form or shape "in order"?

However, apparently what you want is to keep the number and the string together, *in the order that you specify*.

Your mistake, if you'll excuse me for perhaps sounding a bit harsh, is that you seem to think that you can use indices or member names to be both **a means to access data** and **part of the data itself**.

You can't, and you shouldn't. An index is an index, a name is a name, and data is data <sup>[1]</sup>.

Here are two implementations of keeping your numbers and strings together:

```
var pairs = [
    [0, "zero"],
    [4, "four"],
    [2, "two"]
];
for (var index in pairs) {
    alert(pairs[index][0] + ": " + pairs[index][1]);
};
```

For this one, I keep the pairs of numbers and strings together in arrays of their own: the numbers at position 0, the strings at position 1. I store these arrays in `pairs`.

Then I iterate over array with for/in, which, in each iteration, gives me an index of my `pairs` array.

I then use that index to access the right sub-array in `pairs`, and get the number from position 0 and the string from position 1.

```
var pairs = [
    {number: 0, string: "zero"},
    {number: 4, string: "four"},
    {number: 2, string: "two"}
];
for (var index in pairs) {
    alert(pairs[index].number + ": " + pairs[index].string);
};
```

This one works exactly the same, except of storing the pairs in arrays, I store them in objects.

This has the added bonus of better readability inside the for loop: `pairs[index][0]` and `pairs[index][1]` do not really convey a clear meaning. It tells us nothing more than, "of the pair with the given index, get items 0 and 1".

However, `pairs[index].number` and `pairs[index].name` are much clearer: "of the pair with the given index, give me the number and the name."

_

*Footnotes:*

[1a] *A number is a number*: my bank account number is just that: a means to identify my bank account. It doesn't convey any meaning as to my name, my PIN, or the balance on my account -- all attributes that would qualify as data belonging to my bank account.

[1b] *A name is a name*: my name is just a name. When you're talking about me, you can use my name to refer to me, so that others know whom you are talking about. My name does not convey any information about my hobbies, my SSN, or what brand of car I have -- all attributes that would qualify as data that would describe certain aspects of me. (However, by convention, you can often tell a person's gender by their name)

Comment: What makes me think its in any order? The fact that I write it in that order. As for me using member names to access the data and also be apart of it, That is common practice within php, For example if we have a database, we can use the column name(key) to access its value, However your comment seems to make me believe that there is some big difference in arrays within JavaScript in comparison to arrays in PHP, I will go and research now.

Comment: No. Let's say I have a database table that stores bank account information. The name of a column (for example "account_balance") is not part of the data of that column. The data of that column, for any given row, could be 373.24, or -12.47, or 1,000,000. The name "account_balance" says absolutely nothing about my account balance, and it says absolutely nothing about my account number. It is, as you say, used to access it's value. It is not part of that value. And this is the same in databases, PHP, JavaScript, and really everywhere.

Comment: In your main answer, you wrote "An index is an index, a name is a name, and data is data", this can be read that you were talking about 3 parts of the array, which lead me to believe you defined data as the whole array, For clarity would it not have been better to just write a Index is a index, a Value is a value. Furthermore in the opening section of your second comment directly above, you use the term data, whilst in the later section you use the term value. Adhering to your definitions these terms are both used to talk about the same thing, So why not just use one term throughout?