# Force order of array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I cannot seem to access my array via the order I provide, The array constantly reorders itself regardless of how I position its key and value within the array.

An example of what I mean

```
var array = [];
array[1] = 'test';
array[2] = 'dddd';
array[3] = 'aaaa';
array[0] = 'good';

console.log(array)
```

In the console we are left with

```
[Object Array]
0: "good"
1: "test"
2: "dddd"
3: "aaaa"
```

Which is reordered, This is not how I created the array.
I want to access the array how I ordered it, Which would produce the result

```
[Object Array]
1: "test"
2: "dddd"
3: "aaaa"
0: "good"
```

How Can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These answers were already supplied to you in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607807/maintaining-array-order-in-javascript along with references to good documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created the array using indexes that are out of sequence, and then you access the array using indexes in sequence. Of *course* you're going to see a different order.

There is no in-spec way to access those properties in the order you added them, if you add them with out-of-order indexes like that. You'll have to keep track of that separately. E.g.:

```
var array = [];
var order = [];
order.push(1);
array[1] = 'test';
order.push(2);
array[2] = 'dddd';
order.push(3);
array[3] = 'aaaa';
order.push(4);
array[0] = 'good';

var i; // You didn't have this, but you want it

for (i = 0; i < order.length; ++i) {
    alert(array[order[i]]);
}
```

Of course, you'd probably combine the

```
order.push(x);
array[x] = y;
```

...into a function.

Comment: Yes the for loop indeed wasn't a good addition to use as a example, However I was trying to provide another example. In php we can adhere to the order the array was declared by using a foreach loop, Is there not a alternative of this in JavaScript?

Comment: @cecilli0n: Correct, there isn't. The only order is the index order, and even that's somewhat artificial (e.g., the order comes from the numeric relationship of the indexes, not anything intrinsic to the array).

Comment: There is `each` method of an array. But it doesn't solve your problem at all.

Comment: @cecilli0n: If you were using a non-array object, then there is **unspecified** behavior that some engines provide which loops through the keys of the properties you add in the order you add them (using the `for-in` loop), but that is unspecified and not universal, so relying on it is a very bad idea. You pretty much have to keep track yourself, either as above, or by pushing objects onto the array instead (e.g. `array.push({index: 1, value: 'test'})`).

Comment: @cecilli0n: Just to round this out: You can totally build something like PHP's ordered maps ("associative arrays") fairly simply in JavaScript, but it doesn't have such a thing out-of-the-box. I don't think most environments/languages do, they're quite odd ducks. :-) You'd probably do it much like the first example above, except that `array` would probably be a plain object (`{}`), since we don't need the array-ness, and you'd wrap the whole thing up into a unified model.

Answer (score 2):

Just create the array in the order you want it to display. Notice the order of the indexes:

```
array[0] = 'test';
array[1] = 'dddd';
array[2] = 'aaaa';
array[3] = 'good';
```

Or by using `push`:

```
array.push('test');
array.push('dddd');
array.push('aaaa');
array.push('good');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
var array = [];
array[0] = 'test';
array[1] = 'dddd';
array[2] = 'aaaa';
array[3] = 'good';
```